# Explode and unpack column in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, unpack

Assume I have a data with this structure below, how would one explode the column that contains a list then unpack the exploded column?

**Source:**

```
d = { 
    "_id" : "5f2", 
    "connId" : 128, 
    "hospitalList" : [
        {
            "hospitalId" : 29, 
            "boardId" : 1019, 
            "siteId" : 1
        }, 
        {
            "hospitalId" : 3091, 
            "boardId" : 2163, 
            "siteId" : 382
        },
      {
            "hospitalId" : 28, 
            "boardId" : 1017, 
            "siteId" : 5
        }]
    }
```

**Code:**

```
root = pd.json_normalize(d)
nested_cols = [i for i in root.columns if isinstance(root[i][0], list)]
l = [root.drop(nested_cols,1),]
for i in nested_cols:
    l.append(pd.json_normalize(d, record_path=i))

output = pd.concat(l, axis=1)
print(output)
```

**Actual Result:**

```
                        _id      connId  hospitalId       boardId  siteId
0                       5f2       128.0          29         1019       1
1                       NaN         NaN        3091         2163     382
2                       NaN         NaN          28         1017       5
```

**Expected Result:**

```
                        _id      connId  hospitalId      boardId  siteId
0                       5f2       128.0          29         1019       1
1                       5f2       128.0        3091         2163     382
2                       5f2       128.0          28         1017       5
```

Comment: try this: `output.fillna(method='ffill', inplace=True)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This outputs what you want.

```
root = pd.json_normalize(d)
nested_cols = [i for i in root.columns if isinstance(root[i][0], list)]
l = [root.drop(nested_cols,1),]
for i in nested_cols:
    l.append(pd.json_normalize(d, record_path=i))

output = pd.concat(l, axis=1)

output.fillna(method='ffill', inplace=True)
```

Though, unfortunately, I can't know under which circumstances you're going to use the code, and/or if you'll have to make adjustments.

Comment: is there a way to make it dynamic without explicitly specifying the column name like how i've done it

Comment: I think that r-beginners comment solves your problem, I'll insert it to my answer if he doesn't plan to make one of his own. :)